# Mongodb cluster and reading from secondary when primary is down

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is not a basic question on just asking about mongo cluster. It is not a duplicate in my opinion
I have a mongodb 3 node cluster and my url is something along the following lines in a PlayFramework conf file

```
mongodb.uri = "mongodb://mongodb1:27017,mongodb2:27017,mongodb3:27017/myproj"
```

By default when the replica is configured, all reads and writes are happening only on Primary and that is what I want. I however, want the reads to go to secondary when no primary is left, that is when 2 nodes go down, there will not be a primary left and only one secondary.

I do not want to modify my code to achieve this for each read query. I tried the following on the secondary node but it does not help

```
db.getMongo().setReadPref('primaryPreferred')
```

What exactly do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: If "two" out of "three" nodes go down then the Replica set will simply not be available for operations until further intervention.. There is an extensive manual section on the whole subject. Indexed at [Replication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/)

Comment: Not completely true. The replica set won't have a primary yes agreed and I know that. A secondary will still exist. If I blindly mark rs.slaveOK(), I can still do reads on it but I don't want to do that. I want the remaining secondary to allow reads only when there is no primary

Comment: From your "application code" point of view it IS true. Everything else on the subject requires DBA intervention. And therefore becomes a question more suited to [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) because this has nothing to do with the application code. In a similar manner you can also manually "promote" the remaining node. But again, DBA issue. The "code" answer is "it should not care".

Comment: either you are not clear what i am asking or i need to re-phrase my Q. The intent is not to use a manual intervention but to use the options of ?readPreference=secondary&maxStalenessSeconds=

Comment: And you are being told you cannot. You "must" manually intervene. How is that hard to understand? The real thing you should be focusing on is not letting the majority of nodes go down in the first place.

Comment: If your intent is to only read from a secondary if a primary is unavailable, the [`primaryPreferred`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-preference/#primaryPreferred) read preference (with optional `maxStalenessSeconds` in MongoDB 3.4+) is what you're looking for. However, you need to set this parameter from the driver or application point of view (i.e. in your PlayFramework configuration or application). Setting a read preference in the `mongo` shell only affects the current shell session.

Comment: thanks @Stennie, i tried doing some reading on how to do it in play, and tried the following, but even then it wants a primary to exist. Any thoughts on what could be wrong in the below syntax?
mongodb.uri = "mongodb://mongodb1:27017,mongodb2:27017,mongodb3:27017/myproj?readPreference=secondary&maxStalenessSeconds=180"

Comment: It looks like you are missing the `replicaSet=...` parameter (which has to match your configured replica set name) so you are probably getting a direct connection to the first host listed rather than a replica set connection with failover. What MongoDB driver & version are you using, and what version of Play Framework? For more information on MongoDB connection string format and options, see: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/.

Comment: The `replicaSet` value is the name/_id of the replica set, which should be common for all members of the same set: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf._id. The list of replica set members that you provide in the connection string is a seed list used to discover the current replica set configuration (but only if you connect in "replica set mode" by specifying the `replicaSet` name). Can you confirm versions of the PlayFramework and MongoDB driver you are using? That will make it easier to ensure we are talking about the same config.

Comment: yes i got it, trying now, you are spot on in your suggesitons, however, i wonder if that is a mandatory param, based on docs it does not seem so to me. May I ask @Stennie why u think it is mandatory to have replicaSet= in the url

Comment: here is how i have it like this now, before i test it, what do u think of this mongodb.uri = "mongodb://mongodb1:27017,mongodb2:27017,mongodb3:27017/myproj?readPreference=secondary&replicaSet=mongocluster"

and i create my cluster like this
rs.initiate({ _id: "mongocluster", members: [{ _id: 1, host: "mongodb1:27017" }, { _id: 2, host: "mongodb2:27017" }, { _id: 3, host: "mongodb3:27017" }], settings: { getLastErrorDefaults: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 30000 }}})

so this must work now the url i give?

Answer (score 10):

> I do not want to modify my code to achieve this for each read query. I tried the following on the secondary node but it does not help:

```
db.getMongo().setReadPref('primaryPreferred')
```

You are on the right track with read preferences, but need to set this in your connection string or driver. Setting a read preference in the `mongo` shell only affects the current shell session, and has no effect on remote connections.

> mongodb.uri = "mongodb://mongodb1:27017,mongodb2:27017,mongodb3:27017/myproj"

You need to add some additional parameters as per MongoDB's [Connecting String URI Format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/):

- (required) The [`replicaSet=...`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#replica-set-option) option indicates that the driver should use "replica set" connection mode as opposed to the default direct connection mode. This parameter enables replica set monitoring, read preferences, and discovery of topology changes. The provided replica set name must match the [replica set name](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf._id) configured for your deployment. For full details on the connection behaviour expected for officially supported MongoDB Drivers, see the [Server Discovery and Monitoring (SDAM)](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-discovery-and-monitoring/server-discovery-and-monitoring.rst) specification. The [rationale](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-discovery-and-monitoring/server-discovery-and-monitoring.rst#rationale) section of the spec includes answers to common questions about the chosen approach.
- (required) The `readPreference=primaryPreferred` option indicates the preference to read from a primary but use a secondary if there is no primary available.
- (optional) In MongoDB 3.4+ you can specify a [`maxStalenessSeconds=...`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/#replica-set-read-preference-max-staleness) option which limits the maximum replication lag (or staleness) when using a secondary read preference. By default there is no max staleness so the driver will not consider replication lag when selecting a secondary based on read preference. If your intent is to use `primaryPreferred` as a failover option for reads I would set max staleness with caution: you need to ensure that you have at least one secondary which has acceptable staleness.

So, assuming a replica set name of `mongocluster` and database of `myproj` the suggested connection string would be:

```
mongodb://mongodb1:27017,mongodb2:27017,mongodb3:27017/mypr‌oj?replicaSet=‌mongocluster&readPreference=primaryPreferred
```

Comment: Hi @Stennie, I see this in my play logs, so does that mean i am out of luck?
reactivemongo.api.MongoDriver - Some options were ignored because they are not supported (yet): replicaSet

Also, i tried reading the link to understand why is replicaSet really needed but not very clear why. Either way, I will assume your suggestion that it is mandatory but is it being ignored by play framework?

Comment: @curiousengineer What MongoDB driver & version are you using, and what version of Play Framework? In regards to replica set connection the difference is in how the driver discovers and monitors topology. The SDAM spec is a weighty read, but at a high level there are three categories of connection topologies (Standalone, Replica Set, or Sharded). Without the `replicaSet` parameter you are usually connected in `Standalone` mode to the first host specified (i.e. there is no discovery or monitoring of the replica set configuration, and no support for read preferences).

Comment: I am using Mongodb 3.4(docker container image). My play version is addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.10") so I am guessing it is 2.5.10
When you say Mongodb driver version, I am not sure how do I know that. But since we use reactive mongo, here is the dependency for that 
"org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.12.0"

Answer (score 1):

For me, this was very simple:
I just connect to the secondary node/instance using

```
mongosh --port 27018
```

and then I type:

```
db.getMongo().setReadPref('secondary');
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).